# Split a list : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, list, url

I would like to create a list, in which every element would be a line of a file online. But when I want to split my list, I receive the EM : "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". I already tried to solve this issue with decode('utf8') but I couldn't. Any advices ?

```
def collect_record(name):
file = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/%s.txt" %name
u=urllib.request.urlopen(file)
pdblines=u.readlines() 
for line in pdblines :
    line = ligne.strip()
    pdblines = line.split("b")
u.close()
return pdblines
```

Comment: You need to add the full traceback to your post. Also, you have a typo in your code. `ligne.strip()`. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a text file, you shouldn't have to do anything in particular.

```
def collect_record(name):
    file = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/%s.txt" % name
    lines = [i for i in urllib.request.urlopen(file)]
    return lines
```

If you want to be more explicit

```
def collect_record(name):
    file = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/%s.txt" % name
    lines = str(urllib.request.urlopen(file).read()).split('\n')
    return lines
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!